# OPEN LDAP Sync Test

Tags: ldap, openldap, slapd, ldapmodule

Could someone experienced in open ldap give me answers for these questions please ?

1. I'm looking into a pre configured two open ldap servers that are in mirror sync. What is the best way to identify that these two are actually in sync?
2. what are entryCSN and contextCSN in open ldap

Answer (score 0):

`contextCSN` is a `CSN` from the `LDAP Sync provider`:

> The LDAP Sync provider maintains a contextCSN for each database as the current synchronization state indicator of the provider content. It is the largest entryCSN in the provider context such that no transactions for an entry having smaller entryCSN value remains outstanding. The contextCSN could not just be set to the largest issued entryCSN because entryCSN is obtained before a transaction starts and transactions are not committed in the issue order.

[LDAP Sync Replication documentation](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin23/syncrepl.html)

A `CSN` is:

> The Change Sequence Number (CSN) used by OpenLDAP to identify changes in a replicated configuration. CSNs appear to be only defined in an expired RFC draft draft-chu-ldap-csn-xx.txt and for version 2.4 in this FAQ to consist of a timestamp - including microseconds, an operation-within-second counter (6 octets), a 3 octet replica id (as defined by ServerID) and a 6 octet counte-within-modify operation.

[LDAP Glossary](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/apd/)

The 2 nodes are in sync when the `contextCSN` is identical on both nodes.